# MySQL - Does Federated Engine have to be enabled on both servers?

Tags: mysql, federated

I am attempting to run a single MySQL query, joining two databases on two servers.
I am aware of the potential poor performance, but would like to test regardless.

The purpose of this test, I am working on a Windows domain, with a development (local) server and a live (remote) server.

The local server has `FEDERATED` engine `enabled` and the remote server, which stores the actual data but `FEDERATED` engine is `disabled`.

Both tables (live and federated) have the same definition/schema, and the federated table on the local server has been defined:

```
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
CONNECTION='mysql://remote_user@remote_server/remote_database/remote_table';
```

The local server table creates fine, and  although the `remote_user` and `remote_user@'MY-PC-NAME'` has the correct `GRANTS`, I am getting an error:

`ERROR 1429 (HY000): Unable to connect to foreign data source: Access denied for user 'remote_user'@'MY-PC-NAME' (using password`

My question is do **both** the local and remote servers require the `FEDERATED` engine to be enabled?

If not, is there anything else I need to do to get the federated table 
to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FEDERATED` engine option **is not required** to be enabled on both servers, in this case, only the *local server* where the federated table is stored, requires to be enabled.

It turns out that the `remote_user` user requires the `PASSWORD` option.

I used this to get the connection to work:

```
CONNECTION='mysql://remote_user:password@remote_server/remote_database/remote_table';
```

Comment: So to be extra clear by "*only the local server where the federated table is stored*", this means it needs enabled on the server which you create the federated table using the `ENGINE=FEDERATED`.... if **federated** is not in the mysql ini config file under the `[mysqld]` section, then you'll see an error about the MySQL not supporting the federated file system type or something to that effect.